# XmlNode clone() very slow in XPath queries in XML

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I have a requirement where in there is a big XML document. I have to select lot of nodes using XPath from the document based on some condition. Then after I select the XmlNodes, I have to add new properties to the selected nodes and insert it back in many places in XmlDocument.

I found out that when I modify the selected XmlNode, the actual XmlDocument is also getting modified. **So I thought of using xmlNode.Clone() method on the entire list of selected XmlNodes**. **But it is really very very slow**. I mean is there a better way to do it?? Or is clone really very slow??

By the way, I am using XmlDocument to load the Xml document.

Edits HERE :::

I am adding more details to my question. I am using C# language and .net 3.5 as platform.

I have databound this Xml to a datagrid and allowing the user to modify the datagrid. Based on some condition, when the user modifies a cell in a datagrid, I have to select some nodes in Xml and then create new nodes and add it to the XmlDocument that is in memory. So after selecting the objects, I was using clone() which is very very slow for me!!

More Edits HERE::

The original XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grids>   
    <row>
       <value actualvalue="test1" id="0001" valuetype="Constant"/> // i want to make copy of this node whose id = 0001 and make some changes to it
    <value actualvalue="test2" id="0002" valuetype="String"/>
   </row>  
</grids>
```

Then i want to modify the node and the converted XML should be as follows: New node has been added and ids have been reordered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grids>   
    <row>
       <value actualvalue="test1" id="0001" valuetype="newConstant"/> 
       <value actualvalue="test1" id="0002" valuetype="Constant"/> 
    <value actualvalue="test2" id="0003" valuetype="String"/>
   </row>  
</grids>
```

Hope my details are sufficient!!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with XPath or query.

Comment: @Dimitre : I have added more detail. I would say may be the functions in .net is causing slower performance for me!!

Comment: @Guru-Charan: This can be done quite efficiently with XSLT. Please, provide in your question a sample XML document (as minimal as possible) and the wanted result and explain what the transformation should do to convert the source XML document to the result.

Comment: @Dimitre: I have added details to my question? Is my question more clear now?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete XSLT solution.

Answer (score 2):

Other XSLT solution with "fine grained traversal":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="pSearchId" select="1"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:param name="pIdIncrement" select="0"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[1]|@*">
                <xsl:with-param name="pIdIncrement" select="$pIdIncrement"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pIdIncrement" select="$pIdIncrement"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="value">
        <xsl:param name="pIdIncrement"/>
        <xsl:if test="@id = $pSearchId">
            <value actualvalue="{@actualvalue}" 
                   id="{@id}" 
                   valuetype="new{@valuetype}"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="identity">
            <xsl:with-param name="pIdIncrement" 
                            select="$pIdIncrement + (@id = $pSearchId)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="value/@id">
        <xsl:param name="pIdIncrement"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(.+$pIdIncrement,'0000')"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<grids>
    <row>
        <value actualvalue="test1" id="0001" valuetype="newConstant"/>
        <value actualvalue="test1" id="0002" valuetype="Constant"/> // i want to make copy of this node whose id = 0001 and make some changes to it
        <value actualvalue="test2" id="0003" valuetype="String"/>
    </row>
</grids>
```

Comment: @Alejandro - [ I am posting the same comment which I posted to @Robert ] Thanks for the answer. I have less knowledge on XSLT so finding a bit hard to understand your solution presently :) But I have started learning it and I will implement your solution soon and let you know if it solves my problem :)

Comment: @Guru Charan: You are wellcome.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suspect that the culprit here is this:

> I have databound this Xml to a datagrid and allowing the user to modify the datagrid.

Data binding kills performance.  When an object is bound to the UI, all changes to that object are dynamically reflected in changes to the UI.  If you're making many updates to the object, and each of those changes is being propagated to the UI as you make them, you're inserting the computational cost of the UI components' reformatting and rendering into the middle of your XML update.

If you disable binding, perform the update, and then re-enable binding after the update's done, it's quite likely that the performance issues you're describing will diminish into insignificance.

Comment: Thanks for the info!! But i would like to know how do I disable binding for a DataGrid which is bound to XML and then reenable binding ? Can you throw more light into this :)

Comment: It depends entirely on how you're doing the binding.  I haven't played with the `BindingSource` object in a while (I've moved on to WPF), but as I recall there's a property on it that you can set that will do this.  You may also be able to simply disable the `DataGrid` while you're doing this update; that might work.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pinsertBefore" select="1"/>
 <xsl:param name="pnewActualvalue" select="'test1'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pnewValueType"
      select="'newConstant'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="value">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test=
    "(not(@id >= $pinsertBefore)
    and
      not(following-sibling::value[1]/@id = $pinsertBefore)
      )
    ">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
   </xsl:when>

   <xsl:when test=
    "not(@id >= $pinsertBefore)
    and
     following-sibling::value[1]/@id = $pinsertBefore
    ">
     <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>

     <value actualvalue="{$pnewActualvalue}"
            id="{$pinsertBefore}"
            valuetype="{$pnewValueType}"/>
   </xsl:when>

   <xsl:when test=
    "@id = $pinsertBefore
    and
     not(preceding-sibling::value[1])
    ">
     <value actualvalue="{$pnewActualvalue}"
            id="{$pinsertBefore}"
            valuetype="{$pnewValueType}"/>

     <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="increment"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="increment"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="increment">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="increment"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="value/@id" mode="increment">
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select=". +1"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<grids>
    <row>
       <value actualvalue="test1" id="0001"
       valuetype="Constant"/>
       <!-- i want to make copy of this node
       whose id = 0001 and make some changes to it
       -->
    <value actualvalue="test2" id="0002"
           valuetype="String"/>
   </row>
</grids>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<grids>
   <row>
      <value actualvalue="test1" id="1" valuetype="newConstant"/>
      <value actualvalue="test1" id="2" valuetype="Constant"/><!-- i want to make copy of this node
       whose id = 0001 and make some changes to it
       -->
      <value actualvalue="test2" id="3" valuetype="String"/>
   </row>
</grids>
```

**Do note**:

1. **The *identity* template** copies every node "as-is".
2. **The template matching `value` distinguishes four cases**, in one of them the node is copied as is, in another the node is copied and its `id` attribute is incremented, and in two of the cases the node is copied (with or without incrementing its `id` attribute) and the new `value` element is created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have less knowledge on XSLT so finding a bit hard to understand your solution presently :) But I have started learning it and I will implement your solution soon and let you know if it solves my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the question has to do with XPath if the Clone method is the problem. Please first tell us what language and platform you use. I suspect from XmlNode and XmlDocument that you are using the .NET framework but you haven't really told us. 
As for alternatives, changing/transforming/inserting nodes can also be done with XSLT (although you don't make changes on an existing object that way, you create a new result). Whether that performs better I don't know, you would need to measure that to know exactly.

Comment: I have added more detail to the question. You have mentioned " Inserting elements can be done using XSLT " Can u elaborate more on this?? Because I want to make changes in the existing XmlDocument object loaded into memory and after all the changes save the Xml in different file.